# How to handle different Headers in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs(Nextjs) and i have different "Header" for home page and different header for rest of pages,So i want to know that how can i use different headers in nextjs,I created "Layout.js" and put "Header" and "footer" inside this and use/import this file in "_app.js", but how can we do this for different headers ?
Here is my _app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
     <Layout>
     <Component {...pageProps} />
     </Layout>
    </>
   );
}
export default MyApp
```

Comment: I'd recommend a read through [Per-Page Layouts
 documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new layout for your homepage, say `HomeLayout`.
2. Attach this `HomeLayout` as a property `getLayout` on your homepage component.

```js
// src/pages/index.js
import HomeLayout from 'layout/HomeLayout';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Home page </h1>
    );
};

Home.getLayout = HomeLayout;

export default Home;
```

3. Use this newly attached property on `_app.js` to conditionally determine which layout to render. If there exists `getLayout` on a component, we use that layout else we will fallback to our default `Layout`.

```
// _app.js
import Layout from '../components/layout'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const AppLayout = Component.getLayout || Layout;
    return (
      <AppLayout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AppLayout>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Reference:

1. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts

Comment: i am getting following error "Property 'getLayout' does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent<{}> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext): {} | Promise<{}>; }"

Comment: @Rick did you solve that? Seems like a type error